# Wordpress Replace Pagination with Numbers

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this old school pagination like so:

```
<?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
            <nav class="post-nav">
                <ul class="pager">
                    <li class="previous"><?php next_posts_link(esc_html__('&larr; Older posts', THEMO_TEXT_DOMAIN)); ?></li>
                    <li class="next"><?php previous_posts_link(esc_html__('Newer posts &rarr;', THEMO_TEXT_DOMAIN)); ?></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

How would I replace a number pagination, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a plugin **WP-PageNavi** (Source: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) or you can do it manually, you can view the codes here https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-numeric-pagination-in-your-wordpress-theme/
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: In the second link you sent me, there is a function called wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav do I put that in my themes functions.php file?

Comment: yes, you have to put that on _functions.php_ and when you call the pagination use this **<?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>** in your theme’s index.php, archive.php, category.php, and any other archive page template.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the trick of ***paginate_links*** function.
Read this documentation link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/

With this you can create numeric pagination link of any custom posts or you can modify your default numeric pagination behavior.